# Android Realm repalce refresh with waitForChange

Tags: android, realm

After v0.91.0, all deprecated methods in Realm are removed including `refresh()`.

I've used `refresh()` like below to make sure that realm instance has up-to-date data.

```
public static <T> T query(RealmActionWithResult<T> runnable, T defaultValue) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(getConfiguration());
    try {
        realm.refresh();
        return runnable.run(realm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return defaultValue;
    } finally {
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

If i replace `refresh()` with `waitForChange()`, it's blocked until next change happens (of course in non-looper thread).

How can i make it not block current thread, but just pass it when current realm is up-to-date one or block if there is something that should wait?

Or if i use Realm like above pattern (every time close it) in non-looper thread like `Schedulers.io` in Rx, does `Realm.getInstance()` return always newest snapshot because per-thread cached instance reference is zero?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to call `refresh` right after calling `getInstance()`. The Realm returned from `getInstance()` will always be up to date.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply!
If it's cached inside realm (used in same thread), is it always newest one?

Comment: @Christian Melchior  Is this true in a thread that does _not_ have a `Looper` attached?

Comment: If it is the first time you open a Realm on a thread it will be up to date regardless of the presence of a looper. Without a looper, it cannot manually update itself though.